# Result being vector values from ctree classification rather than scalar

Tags: r, classification

After I set my response variable as a factor by doing `as.factor(response)`, and I run:

```
tree = ctree(response~., data=trainingset)
```

When I plot this tree: it gives me vector values for y in the graph as an example: 
y=(0.095, 0.905, 0)
I noticed that the 3 values sum up to 1.

But as a matter fact that the actual response variables consist values of 0, 1, 99 only.

Can anyone help me interpret this vector in ctree plot please? Thank you!

In terms of specific code, it looks like the following:

```
response = as.factor(data$response) 
newdata = cbind(predictor.matrix, response)

ind = sample(2, nrow(newdata), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3))
trainData = newdata[ind==1,]
testData = newdata[ind==2,]

tree = ctree(response~., data=trainData)
plot(tree, type="simple")
```

Comment: Those are posterior probabilities for each of your classes; i.e. the posterior probability that observation is ~0.9 (90%) for class `1`.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, I used the command plot(tree, type="simple")

Comment: and to the is.factor() question, the return is TRUE. :)

Comment: in terms of specific code, please see my edited post above in the original. thank you!

Comment: Re the code for converting the `response`, that is not ideal. You want `response` inside `trainingset`. Better would have been `trainingset <- transform(trainingset, response = as.factor(response))`.

Comment: I have added a more comprehensive answer than the comments I made. I'll clean up here by deleting irrelevant comments now. You might do the same once I am done. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are posterior probabilities for each of your classes; i.e. the posterior probability for that node is ~0.9 (90%) for class `1` (assuming your levels for the factor are in the order `c(0, 1, 99)`.

In practical sense, this means that ~90% of the observations in that node are of class `1`, ~5% are class `0` and none of the observations were of class `99`.

What I think is throwing you is that your classes are numeric levels and the plot had posterior probabilities, also numeric. If we look at an example from the **party** package where the response is a factor with character levels, hopefully you'll understand the plot and outputs from the tree better.

From `?ctree`

```
library("party")
irisct <- ctree(Species ~ ., data = iris)
irisct

R> irisct

     Conditional inference tree with 4 terminal nodes

Response:  Species 
Inputs:  Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width 
Number of observations:  150 

1) Petal.Length <= 1.9; criterion = 1, statistic = 140.264
  2)*  weights = 50 
1) Petal.Length > 1.9
  3) Petal.Width <= 1.7; criterion = 1, statistic = 67.894
    4) Petal.Length <= 4.8; criterion = 0.999, statistic = 13.865
      5)*  weights = 46 
    4) Petal.Length > 4.8
      6)*  weights = 8 
  3) Petal.Width > 1.7
    7)*  weights = 46
```

Here, `Species` is a factor variable with levels

```
R> with(iris, levels(Species))
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Plotting the tree shows the numeric posterior probabilities in the terminal nodes:

```
plot(irisct, type = "simple")
```

[image]

A more informative plot though is:

```
plot(irisct)
```

[image]

As this makes it clear that each node has a number of observations from one or more classes. Which is how the posterior probabilities are worked out.

Predictions from the tree are given by the `predict()` method

```
predict(irisct)

R> predict(irisct)
  [1] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
  [7] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
 [13] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa
....
```

You can objtain the posterioro probabilities for each obsevration via the `treeresponse` function

```
R> treeresponse(irisct)[145:150]
[[1]]
[1] 0.00000 0.02174 0.97826

[[2]]
[1] 0.00000 0.02174 0.97826

[[3]]
[1] 0.00000 0.02174 0.97826

[[4]]
[1] 0.00000 0.02174 0.97826

[[5]]
[1] 0.00000 0.02174 0.97826

[[6]]
[1] 0.00000 0.02174 0.97826
```